# MediaPlayer pause doesnt work in android

Tags: android, media-player

I use the following code to pause the play of an audio file. but it doesn't pause. What is wrong with the code. Any suggesstion...

```
boolean play=false;
int flag=0;
mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

`public void onClick(View v) {

            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            if(play==false)
            {
                flag++;
                if(flag==1)
                {
                    playAudio();
                }

                else
                {
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
                mPlay.setText("Pause");
                play=true;
            }
            else if(play==true)
            {
                mPlayer.pause();
                mPlay.setText("Play");
                play=false;
            }
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    play=false;
                    flag=0;
                }
            });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem lays here: `mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`
You're initializing your player on every click, so what you're trying to pause is a completely new player that cannot be paused, cause it doesn't play. You must initialize the player outside of `onClick` method.

Comment: But how would you go about creating a button that starts and pauses the mediaplayer?

Comment: @EGHDK, Just use mediaPlayer.start() and mediaPlayer.pause() to implement the logic, and a flag to toggle the MediaPlayer states. Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: I guess I just don't know where to initialize `mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`

Comment: @EGHDK, Initialize it inside your Activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: Hmm... I will have to start up a new question because I really cannot get it to work properly.

Comment: I was using this media player in service. stressed day, and your this answer has saved my day. thanks